# Kafka Streams Merge Three Streams from MySQL CDC

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have 3 tables in MySQL DataBase, and I am using Debezium Kafka Connector to do the change data capture.

```
TableA order_item: order_item_id, order_id, ...
TableB order: order_id, organization_id, ...
TableC organization: organization_id, type, ...

Downstream service requirement: order_item_id and type
```

I need the order_item_id and type for my downstream services. As you notice, I need the information from these 3 tables. However, the Debezium Kafka Connector will only capture the change data from a single table every time.

Option 1: I am wondering if there is any method in Kafka Streams to join these 3 streams if these 3 tables are updating simultaneously in the MySQL database.

Option 2: On the other side, I feel like I could connect MySQL Database with my Kafka Streams Application. When the message from the TableA order_item comes in, I could go to the MySQL database to find the related type from TableC. But this way may require the query in MySQL every time the message comes in, which may lead extra memory usage.

Thank you for any suggestion or advice.

Comment: Have you read the docs section about joining at least two streams? https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#kstream-kstream-join

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. I will take a look to see if this fit my requirements.